# Need help casting an object being retrieved from an NSMutableArray and displaying its paramater

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray that contains a list of objects of type "MyClass", with each object having a parameter called, "name" that is of type "NSString".  I need to display this list in a TableView, and in my "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method, I have the following line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[SingletonClass sharedInstance].myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]].name;
```

Here, SingletonClass is my DataLayer, and myArray is the NSMutableArray that contains the list of objects.  I am getting the error: "Property 'name" not found on object of type 'id'", so I need to figure out how to correctly cast to "MyClass", and retrieve its "name" parameter so that it can be displayed in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ugly code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = (MyClass *)([[SingletonClass sharedInstance].myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]).name;
```

If you want a bit more readable code, use a message send-style call instead:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[SingletonClass sharedInstance].myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
((MyClass*)[[SingletonClass sharedInstance].myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]).name
```